# How to make a vertical viewpager with custom animation with pageTransformer

Tags: android, animation, android-viewpager, flip, android-pagetransformer

Challenge:
Hi everybody. I need to make a vertical viewPager with a flip effect on pages change.

I'm developing with v19. I've tried several implementations but almost none has worked for me. Only with android-directionalviewpager-1.2.1fixed.jar achieve vertical viewpager it work, but when setting my pageTransformer gave an error. The others did not show the content. I have spent a lot of time implementing a solution but I have not succeeded.

Anyone can help me on how to accomplish my task?.
Excuse my English.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried (edit your Q and add your code).

Comment: how could you fix? I have same problem with you

Answer (score 0):

You could simply copy the source code of ViewPager. Wherever you see it doing something horizontally, change it to do that same thing vertically. Look for things with the letter X or Y, e.g. `getScrollX()` or `getScrollY()`. It will probably take some time and you'll miss a few the first pass, but it's certainly possible (I've done it for one project).

Here's the source: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java